# How to filter with custom column in sales_order_grid.xml in magento 2?

Tags: magento, magento2

I create a custom grid columns for sales_order_grid.xml in magento 2. I created file app/code/MyApp/Sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml and add below code:
This column will display country name of the order.

```
<column name="purchase_from" class="MyApp\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Order\PurchaseFrom">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Purchase Point</label>
                <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
                <sortable>false</sortable>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <options class="MyApp\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Order\PurchaseFrom\Options"/>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
            </settings>
        </column>
```

So, I create file app/code/MyApp/Sales/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Order/PurchaseFrom.php with prepareDataSource function to get country name from order ID.

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $orderId = $item['entity_id'];
                $item[$fieldName] = $this->getCountryName($orderId);
            }
        }

 

        return $dataSource;
    }
```

So, I created options class for user select country in the filter.
app/code/MyApp/Sales/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Order/PurchaseFrom/Options.php

The country name so on grid and display on filter select are OK.
[image]

But when I click Apply filter it displays popup "**Attention Something went wrong.**". and string on page
"**Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state.**"

How filter with custom column value in sales_order_grid ?

Please help me,
Thank you so much,
BienHV